# Finding the first day of a multiple of X years

Tags: java, date, graph, calendar

I've had some real trouble with making a method to do the following: A unix timestamp and an int representing the period of time to get the first date of is passed in, and the method returns a unix timestamp representing the first day of that time. The method I'm using right now uses the Calendar class as follows:

```
public static long firstTime(long in, int period){
    if(period == DAY_OF_FIVE_YEARS){
        period = Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR;
        in -= in%Vars.FIVE_YEARS;
    }
    cal.setTimeInMillis(in*1000L);
    cal.set(period,cal.getActualMinimum(period));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    return cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
}
```

However sometimes I need to get the first day of five years. For instance I'll pass in a date in 1987 and I want the method to return the first day of 1985. The first if statement up there is my attempt at that, but it does not work, and I'm wondering if there is an easier way. Note that DAY_OF_FIVE_YEARS is some int that signifies it and Vars.FIVE_YEARS is a long that is the number of seconds in five years.

Comment: Haven't tried this yet, but how about if _after_ you set up `cal`, then `year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR); cal.roll(Calendar.YEAR, -(year%5));`?  I'm not the greatest `Calendar` expert so I don't know whether this is right without trying it.  I'm guessing that the reason your method isn't working is because of leap years, so that the number of seconds in a five-year period isn't really constant.

Comment: How is five an even number of years?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch More like "an even five-year period" or something--"even" doesn't always mean divisible by 2.

Comment: The question is under-specified.  You can accomplish what you want but you need a stricter definition of what each period means, both in terms of its duration and its endpoints.  You ***cannot*** base this on the number of seconds due to leap seconds getting in the way, the inability to "round" to the beginning of a specific period, the definition of the epoch (what the value 0 means), and the complications of timezones.  Think through all these issues and reformulate the problem.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for pointing out the roll method. It's exactly what was needed! Can't believe I missed it. Also I changed the title to multiple instead of even number, maybe that's a better way of putting it. Either way thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ajb, here is a method that will find the first multiple of some years:

```
    public static final int DAY_OF_FIVE_YEARS = 843521;  //just any unused number
    public static long firstTime(long in, int period){
        cal.setTimeInMillis(in*1000L);
        if(period == DAY_OF_FIVE_YEARS){
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            cal.roll(Calendar.YEAR, -(year%5));
            period = Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR;
        }
        cal.set(period,cal.getActualMinimum(period));
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        return cal.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate                          // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )   // Get a particular date.
.withDayOfYear( 1 )                // Get first of the year.
.minusYears( 1 )                   // Go back a year
```

## Problems with the Question

You are abusing the date-time classes, apparently trying to represent a date-only value in a date-with-time-of-day-and-time-zone class.

> Vars.FIVE_YEARS is a long that is the number of seconds in five years

Your concept of representing five years as a count of seconds is flawed in two ways: (a) days are not always 24 hours long, and (b) years are not always 365 days long.

Another problem: you should be working in date-time objects, rather than passing around a mere count-of-millisecnds integer number. Such numbers make debugging and logging difficult as humans cannot perceive their meaning. So errors and bugs may escape notice. And such numbers may not properly represent intended values, as discussed above.

And you are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by *java.time* classes.

## `Instant`

Parse your count-of-milliseconds-since-epoch as a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( myMillis ) ;
```

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Extract the date from our `ZonedDateTime` above.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

If you want the first day of the year, ask for it.

```
LocalDate firstOfThisYear = ld.withDayOfYear( 1 ) ;  // Get first of the year.
```

Go back as many years as you want.

```
LocalDate firstOfLastYear = ld.minusYears( 1 ) ;
```

If you want to work with first half or second half of a decade (years 0-4 & 5-9), yet the year number and do the math.

```
int year = ld.getYear() ;  // Ex: 2018
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).